# file_get_contents_curl вместо file_get_contents

Tags: curl, php

Доброго времени суток!

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как заменить функцию

```
if (file_get_contents('https://raw.github.com/dekmabot/Asterix-CMS/master/core.txt')) {
    $check_web_access = true;
} else {
    $check_web_access = false;
}
```

с помощью `curl` или `file_get_contents_curl`?

Спасибо!

Comment: А в чем проблема-то...?

Comment: Проблема в том, что хостинг не допускает использование file_get_contents.

Comment: ну тогда curl.

Comment: Ну, а вопрос-то о чем?
Не знаю как это реализовать с curl:(

Comment: а погулить или в поиске набирать текст это сложно?
Я просто к чему клоню, конечно же проще написать сообщение и задать вопрос на форуме и сидеть ждать когда тебе ответят, но ведь за жто время можно и самому ответ найти на просторах инета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php
http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/curl
Я угадал с самоучителями?